# Trying to put in the url with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I'm trying to build this application where users have their usernames in the domain name ( domain.com/hisusername for example) and this is what I did, so this is my route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{username}'], function($username){
    Route::get('/', 'UserController@UserProfile');

});
```

And my controller

```
 public function UserProfile($username){
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    if (!$user) {
        abort(404);
    }

        return view('pages.profile')
            ->with('user', $user);
  }
```

It works fine the problem is when I try to add another route it gets confused with a username and it returns a 404 page, how can I fix that please?

Comment: just put a unique prefix segment before the {username} var

Comment: example: `Route::get('/user/{username}', 'UserController@UserProfile');`  user is unique prefix for user all user {username}

Comment: Its because Laravel thinks `another-route` is a user, order of routes is important.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel renders routes from top to bottom.  Often when I encounter this problem it's because I need to put my 'catch-all' routes below all the others.

That being said, I would strongly suggest doing something like domain.com/u/user instead to avoid conflicts with existing pages.

It may seem like a stretch, but if you ever had a someone with the username 'login' they might never be able to access their account.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'user'], function($username){
    Route::get('/{username}', 'UserController@UserProfile');
    Route::get('/otherinfo', 'UserController@otherinfo');
});
 Route::get('/more/other/route', 'OtherController@methodinfo');
```

in your browser it will display like. sample.com/user/yourUsername

Answer (score 1):

Okay it's seem very easy :

```
Route::get('/{username}', ['uses' => 'UserController@UserProfile']);
```

I don't know why you have to use the group prefix? You just need to define a get routes as normal, you controller look good, it should work ! :)